# How to check compare Validation in View in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In MVC 4 Need to check From And To Values in View like CompareValidator whether the To Value is greater than From Value?

Model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter From")]
public int FROM_RECORDVALUE { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter To")]
public int TO_RECORDVALUE { get; set; }
```

View :

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label class="defaultlable">
            @Model.getPickListMaster().getPickListHeaderName("RECORDVALUE") From
         </label>
          @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FROM_RECORDVALUE, new { @class = "form-control", @maxlength = @Model.getPickListMaster().MAX_LENGTH })
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="form-group">
           <label class="defaultlable">
          @Model.getPickListMaster().getPickListHeaderName("RECORDVALUE") To
           </label>
         @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TO_RECORDVALUE,new { @class = "form-control", @maxlength = @Model.getPickListMaster().MAX_LENGTH})
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

How can i achieve this?. Please give me suggestions.

Comment: Create a custom validation attribute:
`public class IsBiggerThan : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        ....
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}`
http://www.itorian.com/2013/07/custom-data-annotations-or-custom.html

Comment: Yes i tried with Custom Validation also. I'm new in MVC. So i can't achieve my custom Validation Correctly. I don't know how can i pass FROM and TO Values & Model to ValidationAttribute.So Please give me example for checking two values with ValidationAttribute.